# Apply symbology to raster working in Data and Layout view but won't export to jpg correctly

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, export, addlayer

I'm trying to export a series of jpg maps by displaying and symbolizing raster layers one at a time. The Data View and Layout View in ArcMap 10.7 correctly reflect the symbology of the .lyr file I want to use, but when I export the image, the symbology of the raster is a bunch of randomly chosen colors, and there is no consistency between images (e.g. a whole new set of colors is chosen each time). I'm using ArcPy within the ArcMap scripting box, not doing standalone python.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env 
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import mapping
import os

#variables to look through
folders = ['folder1', 'folder2','folder3']

scn_no = range(len(folders))
yearlist = range(2020,2110,10)

#make object out of map document (your .mxd file):
map_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\MyDocuments\mymap.mxd")

#make object out of dataframe
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(map_mxd, '*')[0] 
#reference symbology layer file
symbfile = r'C:\Users\Folder1\mysymbology.lyr'

for i in scn_no:
    env.workspace = folders[i]
    sc = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif')
    for y in range(len(yearlist)):
        year = yearlist[y]
        inras = sc[y] #set raster to visualize

        arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbfile)
        #load yearly rasters into map one at a time
        #creates temporary display file for each raster
        result = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(inras, 'tempras.tif') #create temporary display raster, stored in Local app data file
        layer1 = result.getOutput(0) #make temporary display raster into a layer in the map document 
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer1) #add the layer to the dataframe

        #apply symbology from .lyr file
        symb = arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbfile)
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer1, symb)
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        print(y) #progress check

        #exporting the jpg
        x = str(inras)
        out_jpg = str(scenario[i]) + '_' + x.replace('.tif', '.jpg')
        outpath = r'C:\Users\MyDocuments\outfolder'
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(map_mxd, outpath + "\\" + out_jpg, "PAGE_LAYOUT", 2400, 3000, 600) #width and height dimensions and resolution
```

Comment: It feels consistent with arcpy -  try `map_mxd.save()` before the export line

Comment: I tried that and got a different error: "IOError: MapDocObject: Unable to save.  Check to make sure you have write access to the specified file and that there is enough space on the storage device to hold your document."  I am the only one working on this document, I have write access, and I have plenty of space on my harddrive, so I'm not sure why it's telling me that. Closing and reopening ArcMap did not change the error message.

Comment: Sounds familiar, You should probably save it in another name, there are some several questions here on that subjuct